# Problems with migration apache-poi from 3.17 to 4.1.1

Tags: apache-poi, openxml, xmlbeans, jxpath

After updating Apache POI from 3.17 to 4.1.1 i'm getting this error message:

> org.apache.commons.jxpath.JXPathNotFoundException: No value for xpath:
>   /xxxx/value  at
>   org.apache.commons.jxpath.ri.JXPathContextReferenceImpl.getValue(JXPathContextReferenceImpl.java:383)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.jxpath.ri.JXPathContextReferenceImpl.getValue(JXPathContextReferenceImpl.java:313)

Here is my pom:

```xml
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

My setup:

JDK 8
WildFly 10

JXPath - the last version is 1.3
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-jxpath/commons-jxpath

Comment: Please show the code which throws that exception. Btw.: `apache poi 4.1.1` needs `ooxml-schemas 1.4`, see https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components. And it does **not** need `JXPath`at all. So please show the code which throws that exception and the complete stack trace.

Comment: Added languages support for better lisibility